# Incomplete data displayed from query

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to make an update form using PHP, getting my data from MySQL 5. I have the fields set as a TINYTEXT type. My problem is when I attempt to display a field in my form for editing, the display stops at the first space. For example: my database my have "John Doe" in one field, but when I attempt to display that field I only see "John". Here is a portion of my code:

```
$id =mysql_real_escape_string ($_GET['id']);
if(isset($_POST['update'])) {
$UpdateQuery = "UPDATE members SET business_name='$_POST[business_name]', phone='$_POST[phone]', fax='$_POST[fax]', address1='$_POST[address1]', address2='$_POST[address2]', city='$_POST[city]', state='$_POST[state]', zip='$_POST[zip]', website='$_POST[website]', contact='$_POST[contact]',  email='$_POST[email]', update_flag='$_POST[update_flag]',  WHERE id='$id'";
mysql_query($UpdateQuery, $con);
}
$sql = "SELECT * FROM members WHERE id = $id";
$my_Data = mysql_query($sql,$con);

while($record = mysql_fetch_array($my_Data)) {
?>
<form action=listingupdate.php method=post>

    <tr><input type=text name=business_name value=<?=$record['business_name']?> ></tr></br>
    <tr><input type=text name=phone value=<?=$record['phone']?> > </tr></br>
    <tr><input type=text name=fax value=<?=$record['fax']?> > </tr></br>
```

I have been googling several different ways, but I have not found what I am doing wrong. Would someone be so kind as to show my what I need to do to get all of the data in a field to display in my form?

Comment: You left out the double quotes
<input type="text" name="business_name" value="<?=$record['business_name']?>" >

Answer (score 0):

Well a few things.. You should be using mysqli, not mysql since it is deprecated. Also you're calling mysql_real_escape_string on the id, but none of the other data so your script is wide open to SQL injection attacks. It looks like your code will fail if any of the posted data contains apostrophes. I'm not sure how you're planning to use GET and POST at the same time since your form, when submitted doesn't submit a GET value. With all that said, you should check the database to see if names are getting truncated in there, or if it's a client side issue.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I will look into changing the code into mysqli. I guess it may not be necessary, but I have just used mysql_real_escape_string anytime I pass a variable through a url. Not sure how to get the value that I passed using post. The database was not truncating in there. I appears that tyro was correct, I simply forgot to double quote my parameters. I do appreciate your comments and I will look into incorporating your suggestions.